# Если нет элемента на странице код JS не срабатывает и останавливает последующий код

Tags: javascript

Подскажите с базой по JS. 
Есть сайт и код на чистом JS. Некоторый Код действует только для главной странице, ну то есть именно там находятся элементы на которые воздействует JS. Соответственно когда мы переходим на другую страницу этих элементов нет и консоль выдаёт ошибку
 (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null) 
и весь последующий код не работает.

Как правильно избежать такой ситуации?

Что интересно, на JQ такого нет.

JS файл подключаю в индексной странице перед /body. 
Пример кода:

```
var openHeader = document.getElementById('openForm');
openHeader.addEventListener('click', function(){
    modalForm.classList.add('modal-success__wrapper--active');
});
```

Comment: проверку сделай if(!openHeader) return; (или что то другое)

Comment: добавь пример разметки, и пример с jquery который работает